# My voice assistant program doesn't register anything I say

Tags: python, speech-recognition, pyttsx3

I downloaded a python code from GitHub.

It doesn't register anything I'm saying.

My code:

```
import openai
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr
from api_key import API_KEY

openai.api_key = API_KEY
engine = pyttsx3.init()

r = sr.Recognizer()
mic = sr.Microphone(device_index=0)
conversation = ""
user_name = "You"
bot_name = "DAI"

while True:
    with mic as source:
        print("\nlistening...")
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=0.2)
        audio = r.listen(source)
    print("no longer listening.\n")

    user_input = r.recognize_google(audio)
    prompt = user_name + ": " + user_input + "\n" + bot_name+ ": "
    conversation += prompt  # allows for context

    # fetch response from open AI api
    response = openai.Completion.create(engine='text-davinci-003', prompt=conversation, max_tokens=100)
    response_str = response["choices"][0]["text"].replace("\n", "")
    response_str_split = response_str.split(user_name + ": ", 1)[0].split(bot_name + ": ", 1)[0]

    conversation += response_str_split + "\n"
    print(response_str_split)

    engine.say(response_str_split)
    engine.runAndWait()
```

I get this error:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.11 /Users/danieforsell22b/Desktop/GPT3VoiceBot/gpt3Bot.py 

listening...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/danieforsell22b/Desktop/GPT3VoiceBot/gpt3Bot.py", line 27, in <module>
    user_input = r.recognize_google(audio)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 879, in recognize_google
    flac_data = audio_data.get_flac_data(
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 495, in get_flac_data
    flac_converter = get_flac_converter()
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 1744, in get_flac_converter
    raise OSError("FLAC conversion utility not available - consider installing the FLAC command line application by running `apt-get install flac` or your operating system's equivalent")
OSError: FLAC conversion utility not available - consider installing the FLAC command line application by running `apt-get install flac` or your operating system's equivalent
no longer listening.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: What happens if you replace `continue` under `except:` by `raise`?

Comment: I get this error: https://pastebin.com/jaeprk29

Comment: As mentioned I haven't made this code myself, only made some modifications. I suppose i need a api for the google text to speech. And its not free, and i can't use the free trail either.

I will try to find another api thats free, feel free to suggest

Comment: Have you read the error message? It says that you need to install FLAC.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Windows? It seems either you do not have flac installed on your machine or the library code can not find it. If you are using Windows, try to install flac first and modify the `__init__.py` of the speech recognition library like this.

from

```
flac_converter = shutil_which("flac")
```

to

```
flac_converter = shutil_which("flac.exe")
```

Comment: No because im using mac